# Does focal length change?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, water, geometric-optics

Suppose we immersed spherical mirror in water , does its focal length changes, if yes or no please explain your assertion.

If it is cut horizontally half way between does its focal length remains same?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no because the principle that sets the ray geometry is the law of reflection, and this law does not change if the mirror is immersed in water: the reflection angles still equal the incidence angles. So any ray diagram for the device is unchanged.

As for your question about cutting the mirror. The focal length of any spherical arc is always the same and given by half the sphere's radius. If you cut some of the mirror away, though, this will obviously mean that some of the incoming light is no longer reflected through the focus, and the numerical aperture, thus resolution, of the device when used for form an image will decrease accordingly.

Comment: The OP asked a good question.  The focal length of a mirror doesn't change when it is immersed in water, but the focal length of a lens DOES change.  I think I would like to pose such a question to my high school physics students at some point.